# C# Linked-list can't understand add method

Tags: c#, linked-list

Can't understand how Head is getting the data that is passed to curr. Would be great if somebody gave a clear explanation

```
class LinkedListService
{
    private Service Head; 
    public LinkedListService()
    {
        Head = null;
    }
    public void add(Service data)
    {
        Service curr = Head; 
        if (Head == null)
        {
            Head = data;
        }
        else
        {
            while (curr.Next != null)
            {
                curr = curr.Next;
            }
            curr.Next =  data; // how does Head receive the data that is passed to curr ?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How should we guess `Service` class implementation?

Comment: What is your question ? whatever u ve asked here is not completely  related to the code. Show your complete code

Answer (score 0):

```
curr.Next =  data; // how does Head receive the data that is passed to curr ?
```

It doesn't. In the first line `curr` is pointed towards the object `Head`.

```
Service curr = Head;  //    curr --> Head
```

now if `Head` is not initialized yet, meaning : `if (Head == null)` it will take the data and point `Head` to the same address in memory where `data` exist in this line:

```
Head = data;
```

If on the other hand the `Head` already exists than the new data has to go to the end of the tail. The tail is represented as a series of elements which are accessible through the `Next` property:

```
Head | Head.Next --> item2 | item2.Next --> item3 | item3.Next --> null
```

The last item in the tail will have no next item. So it's value will be `null`. The while loop runs through the entire tail as long as there exist a `Next` element and at each step assigns the `Next` element to the `curr`ent element:

```
while (curr.Next != null)
{
    curr = curr.Next;
}
```

Whe it has reached the last element which has no `Next` item it will take the `Next` property and point it towards the memory address where `data` is situated:

```
curr.Next =  data;
```

No you have one more Item in the list at the end. And again this new item has the Next property pointing to `null`.

Hope it is understandable. If not drop me a comment.